# Get sender language in Chromecast Receiver

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I am trying to get the sender application language from [Chromecast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromecast) receiver in the first connection (before loading any stream) to show a welcome message.

I have this in my sender code to set the options:

```
cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().setOptions({
    receiverApplicationId: castReceiverId,
    autoJoinPolicy: chrome.cast.AutoJoinPolicy.ORIGIN_SCOPED,
    language: languageService.getCurrentLanguage().iso6393,
    resumeSavedSession: true,
});
```

Is there a way to recover these params in the receiver code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found the way to recover init options, but I have set a custom namespace to pass a message through it from sender to receiver once the connection is set.

In Sender:

```
const customNameSpace = 'urn:x-cast:google.cast.custom';
const msg = {lang: senderApplicationLanguage};
context.getCurrentSession().sendMessage(customNameSpace, msg, onSuccess, onError);
```

Then just wait for it in receiver

```
const customNameSpace = 'urn:x-cast:google.cast.custom';
this.context.addCustomMessageListener(customNameSpace, (event) => {
    const lang = event.data.lang;
});
```

Hope this helps someone!